# Como Tornar um Simples Form em HTML responsivo com CSS nativo?

Tags: html, css

Bom galera, fui para uma entrevista de emprego e me pediram para desenvolver um simples formulário com label e input e um textarea, só que esse formulário tem que ser responsivo, e funcionar em todos os tipos de dispositivos.

Eu começei a fazer, segue o código do HTML

**HTML**

```css
.formContato textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.formContato label {
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="formContato">
  
    <div>
      <label>Nome:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <label>E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <label>Mensagem:</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  
  </form>

</div>
```

Estou com dificuldade para torna-lo responsivo, alguém pode me dizer como fazer isso? (Utilizando apenas o CSS nativo)

Comment: HTML puro sempre é responsivo. Começa a deixar de ser quando o designer começa a travar os elementos manualmente.

Comment: Coloca isso no seu CSS por hora ` input, textarea { width: 100%; }`. E vai estudar sobre @media querys, flexbox etc.

Comment: Como assim ? Então só se eu fazer um form, ele se ajusta a qualquer dispositivo ?

Comment: Além disso, se você que está desenvolvendo, você que precisará levantar os requisitos do projeto e definir quando foram satisfeitos ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o famoso "viewport" para fazer esta melhoria, mas, pode-se ficar do jeito que não deseja. Tente definir o viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Um `viewport` fornece instruções ao navegador sobre como controlar as dimensões e o dimensionamento da página.

A `width=device-width` define a largura da página para seguir a largura da tela do dispositivo (que varia dependendo do dispositivo).

A `initial-scale=1.0` define o nível de zoom inicial quando a página é carregada pela primeira vez pelo navegador.

Se você preferir, pode deixar responsivo, manualmente com CSS:

```
    /* Estilos para celulares de no máximo 176 x 220*/
@media all and (max-width: 319px) {

    /*aqui vai o css*/

}



/* Estilos para celulares principais - 320 x 568*/
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 532px) {

    /*aqui vai o css*/

}



/* Estilos para tablet de no mínimo 533 x 853*/

@media all and (min-width: 533px) and (max-width: 800px) {

    /*aqui vai o css*/

}



/* Estilos para desktop/notebook a partir de 801*/

@media all and (min-width: 801px) {

    /*aqui vai o css*/

}
```

Assim você vai fazer as definições manualmente, (responsivo do 0, na unha), caso quer fazer algo rapido, não tenha tempo, use o "viewport".

É isso, não sei se conseguir te ajudar, mas espero que sim!

Comment: O que são esse min-width e max-width, pode me explicar?

Comment: min-width é a largura minima do dispositivo, e max-width é a largura maxima! Esta base que está definida é a media entre os dispositivos! Pode-se usar varias outras definições, mas estas são as principais! Por exemplo: o dispositivo tem 300px de largura, daí vai usar tal css, caso seja diferente de 300px de largura, vai usar outro css, por aí vai! Da uma olhada em: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp , espero que tenha entendido!

Comment: Obrigado, você tem algum site para me recomendar, onde eu consigo ver a largura dos dispositivos?